# Python: Removing spaces and '\n' from list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to delete white spaces and enter's from a list, which i need to import as coordinates. However this does not seem to work. giving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Currently i'm still looking into the removal of the spaces (first these have to be deleted, then the enter's will follow).

Does anyone has any suggestions why this does not work?

the code is as follow:

```
# Open a file
Bronbestand = open("D:\\Documents\\SkyDrive\\afstuderen\\99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2\\scripting\\testuitlezen4.txt", "r")
headerLine = Bronbestand.readline()
valueList = headerLine.split(",")
#valueList = valueList.replace(" ","")

xValueIndex = valueList.index("x")
yValueIndex = valueList.index("y")
#xValueIndex = xValueIndex.replace(" ","")
#yValueIndex = yValueIndex.replace(" ","")

coordList = []

for line in Bronbestand.readlines():
    segmentedLine = line.split(",")
    coordList.append([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])

coordList2 = [x.strip(' ') for x in coordList]

print coordList2
```

Where the "Bronbestand" is the following:

```
id,x,y,
      1,  -1.24344945,   4.84291601
      2,  -2.40876842,   4.38153362
      3,  -3.42273545,    3.6448431
      4,  -4.22163963,   2.67913389
      5,   -4.7552824,   1.54508495
      6,  -4.99013376, -0.313952595
      7,   -4.7552824,  -1.54508495
      8,  -4.22163963,  -2.67913389
      9,  -3.42273545,   -3.6448431
```

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Comment: you're appending lists to your `coordList`  : `coordList.append([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])`, try `extend()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to roll back the edit.  Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a traditional web forum.  If you have another question, feel free to ask!  However, it is not productive to add a new question to an old question, especially if you have already accepted an answer.  Instead, when you have a new question, press the "Ask Question" button at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is here.  The `append()` method adds a *single item* to the list.  If you append a list to a list, you get a list of lists.

```
coordList.append([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])
```

There are two ways to fix this.

```
# Append separately
coordList.append(segmentedLine[xValueIndex])
coordList.append(segmentedLine[yValueIndex])

# Use extend()
coordList.extend([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])
```

Alternatively, if you meant to have a list of lists, you'll need to iterate two levels deep.

```
coordList2 = [[x.strip(' ') for x in y] for y in coordList]
```

Comment: Hi, this works great!
However, by solving this problem a seccond problem comes up. it gives me trouble to convert the list items to integers due to negative numbers en floating numbers. See edited question above.

Again thank you already for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
buff = csv.DictReader(Bronbestand)

result = []

for item in buff:
    result.append(dict([(key, item[key].strip()]) for key in item if key])) # {'y': '-3.6448431', 'x': '-3.42273545', 'id': '9'}
```

your data is valid Comma seperated Values (CSV) try to use the native python csv parser.

Answer (score 0):

`coordList` is a list of two-element lists.

If you want it to be that way, your `strip` line should be:

```
coordList2 = [[x[0].strip(' '), x[1].strip(' ')] for x in coordList]
```

Answer (score 0):

`coordList` is 2 levels deep here, so you should do something like:

```
coordList2 = [[a.strip(' '), b.strip(' ')] for a, b in coordList]
```

but more descriptive names than `a` and `b` could be good!

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in Bronbestand.readlines():
    segmentedLine = line.split(",")
    coordList.append(segmentedLine[xValueIndex])
    coordList.append(segmentedLine[yValueIndex])
```

Previously you were appending lists to `coordList`, rather than strings, because of an extra `[]` pair.

This meant that the `x` in your list comprehension (`coordList2 = [x.strip(' ') for x in coordList]`) was a list, which doesn't have a `strip()` method.

Comment: The `append()` method only takes one parameter these days.  (It used to take more.)

Comment: Thanks, missed that one! Edited taking that into account

Answer (score 0):

You're appending lists to your `coordLis`.

`coordList.append([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])`

Better use `extend()`. For example:

```
In [84]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [85]: lis.append([4,5])

In [86]: lis
Out[86]: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]  # list object is appended

In [87]: lis.extend([6,7])     #use extend()

In [88]: lis
Out[88]: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6, 7]     #6 and 7 are appended as normal elements
```